# Authentication_InvalidCredentials: => The server has rejected the client credentials

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-business-central

I am trying to get the Customer List from the **Business Central** through **Authorization Token**. And it's returning the token when I am passing to get the customer list, it's throwing error.

> {"error":{"code":"Authentication_InvalidCredentials","message":"The server has rejected the client credentials.  CorrelationId:  ec8e4ab3-ae04-4454-9038-395ff74aeed8."}}

For this I tried below code.

```
 ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential("xxx", "xxx");
                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/6fed243c-78g7-405a-8g78-xxxxx", true);//tried with URL=> https://login.windows.net/6fed243c-78g7-405a-8g78-xxxxx also
                AuthenticationResult authenticationResult2 = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com", clientCredential).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                var nav = new NAV.NAV(new Uri("https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/6fed243c-78g7-405a-8g78-xxxxx/BC18Sandbox/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS USA, Inc.')"));
                nav.BuildingRequest += (sender, eventArgs) => eventArgs.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticationResult2.AccessToken);

                var customerList = nav.Customer.ToArray();
```

Can you please suggest me why the token is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the OData Web Service which is not the same as calling the API. They are two different things exposing some of the same data.

Try calling the API instead e.g.:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/<your tenant domain>/<environment name>/api/v2.0
```

You can find a short explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-connect-apps#calling-the-api).

Comment: I think the token works with either system.